# Is there anything similar to TouchDown for iOS?

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, android

Is there any app like NitroDesk's [TouchDown](http://www.nitrodesk.com/) Android email client for iOS?

Just for background info, many companies force you to have the latest version of iOS installed to access Exchange Server, or you can have a secure client like TouchDown. That means you're out of luck if you're on an unsupported phone such as iPhone 2G which cannot have the latest version of iOS and cannot run TouchDown since it's Android only.

**EDIT:**

I know the latest version of iOS Mail App has similar features to TouchDown. I'm asking this question because some users may have an iPhone 3G which will not be upgradeable to iOS 4.3, hence they will not be able to access Exchange from their iPhone unless there is an app similar to TouchDown available.

Comment: If a user is running a version of iOS that is unsupported by Apple, then it will also be unsupported by most third party developers. Tell them to upgrade to newer hardware, the 3G is almost four years old now and there isn't much excuse to still be using one. Android is full of users stuck on old software, but most iOS users do keep their software up to date, and if a user's budget is too tight to keep their hardware up to date, then most of them won't be willing to buy third party software either. So smart third party developers don't waste time supporting old hardware.

Comment: Good point. With all the iOS apps out there though I thought there might be something out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish. I am running Touchdown on three android devices, and cannot get Exchange 2003 to work on a single iOS device.

The problem? Apple does not support anything but EAS (Active Sync) so, if there is no Active Sync on your exchange server, you're toast - or you need to deal with your IT staff - and I bet security will be an issue.

Answer (score 3):

how about the iOS version of TouchDown? :-)

http://nitrodesk.com/touchdown/ios/

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/touchdown-for-ios/id560596861?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

Try Outlook Web Email - http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/outlook-web-email/id428974099?mt=8

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Thanks for your answer! Can you please add more information about the software you mentioned? What features of Outlook Web Email make it the right choice for the OP?